# помогите с округлением до большего числа

Tags: java, android

помогите с округлением до большего числа...

```
double m =  double x(10.05) / (double h(2.8) + 0.10); =3.4
 int result2 = (int)Math.floor(m); = 3

double r1 = double f(11.6) / double z(0.53); =21.8
int result = (int)Math.ceil(r1); =22

double n = Double.valueOf(result / result2); = 7.0
```

У меня получается ответ 7.0, а надо что бы получился 7.3 ибо (22/3 получается 7.3) помогите, не понимаю почему так?

Comment: сделайте вашу result тоже double или double n = (double)result / result2

Comment: У вас идет целочисленное деление. Отсюда и округление.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double n = ((double) result) / result2;
```

Операции с int обычно возвращают int. А int - это всегда целые числа.

Answer (score 4):

У вас идет целочисленное деление. При целочисленном деление результат округляется вниз к целому числу. Нужно, чтобы один из параметров был дробным, в данном случае `double`

Answer (score 2):

Деление вида `int/int` приведет к округлению до целого числа с отбрасыванием дробной части. Вам необходимо привести к типу `double` при делении, чтобы осталась дробная часть, например:

```
double n = result * 1.0 / result2;
```

Либо способом, указанным выше в ответах.

Пример на [ideone](http://ideone.com/hAnQrL).